# Laravel implement assertSentFrom specific address Mailable Testing

Tags: laravel, email, testing, phpunit, phpmailer

Trying to get to grips with Mocking and test cases, I want to test that a Mailable `TestMail` is sent *from* company@company.com, the documentation provides `hasTo`, `hasCc`, and `hasBcc` but doesn't look like it uses something like `hasFrom`. Is there any solutions to this?

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mocking#mail-fake

```
public function testEmailAlwaysFrom()
{

    Mail::fake();

    Mail::to('foo@bar.com')->send(new TestMail);

    Mail::assertSent(TestMail::class, function ($mail) {
        return assertEquals('company@company.com', $mail->getFrom());
        // return $mail->hasTo($user->email) &&
        //     $mail->hasCc('...') &&
        //     $mail->hasBcc('...');
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MailFake doesn't provide `hasFrom` method in the class and therefore will return false.

The workaround below however doesn't work when using the environmental variable MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS, `->from()` has to be called within `build()`.

A couple of GitHub issues have been reported suggesting a workaround below:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/20056
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/20059

```
public function testEmailAlwaysFrom()
{

    Mail::fake();

    Mail::to('foo@bar.com')
        ->send(new TestMail);

    Mail::assertSent(TestMail::class, function ($mail) {

        $mail->build(); // <-- workaround
    
        return $mail->hasTo('foo@bar.com') and
            $mail->hasFrom('company@company.com');
        
    });
        
}
```